Dynamics of magnetization in anisotropic ferromagnet
I am currently trying to understand how the magnetization $\mathbf{M}$ of a ferromagnet, possessing different anisotropies (shape and magnetocrystalline anisotropy), behaves in the presence of an external magnetic field, using the Landau-Lifshitz-Gilbert (LLG) equation. An expression for the free energy in this scenario usually contains a Zeeman term for the external field, a demagnetizing term, and a magnetocrystalline anisotropy term. My core issue is translating the expression for the free energy to a dynamic equation for $\mathbf{M}(t)$, i.e. the LLG eq. If there is just the external and the demagnetizing field, the free energy becomes
$$
F = -\mu_0 (\underbrace{\mathbf{H}_\text{ext}+\mathbf{H}_d}_{\mathbf{H}_\text{eff}})\cdot\mathbf{M},
$$
where $\mathbf{H}_\text{ext}$ and $\mathbf{H}_d$ are the external and demagnetizing fields respectively, and the sum of the two is the effective field. The LLG equation is then usually written in terms of this effective field:
$$
\frac{d\mathbf{M}}{dt} = -\gamma\, \mathbf{M}\times\mathbf{H}_\text{eff}+\alpha \,\mathbf{M}\times\frac{d\mathbf{M}}{dt},
$$
giving rise to precession and damping along this field. My question concerns what happens to the above equation, when you take magnetocrystalline anisotropy into account. Does it simply contribute an extra term to the effective field? I imagine this depends on the anisotropy, i.e. if the crystal has an easy axis or easy plane. To be concrete, let the free energy takes the form
$$
F = -\mu_0(\mathbf{H}_\text{ext}+\mathbf{H}_d)\cdot\mathbf{M} + K_u \sin^2\theta,
$$
where $\theta$ is the polar angle of $\mathbf{M}=M(\sin\theta\cos\varphi,\sin\theta\sin\varphi,\cos\theta)$. If we take $K_u<0$, the $xy$-plane is the easy plane. But there is not any preferred direction for the magnetization within the $xy$-plane. How can this be taken into account in the LLG equation?
If there were an easy axis, I think this could just contribute an extra term to the effective field along that axis, but if there is an easy plane, I am not sure.
